# After many successful notification received, It no longer receive any

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM service to push notification to my application. But when I do some functionality testing for my app to make sure everything is working right with the notifications, the device either the real one or the emulator stops from receiving any more notification despite that i get a " Success " sending a notification. Which means after i send like ~5 notification and interact with them if i send any more i no longer can receive any new notification.
So My question is : is there anything wrong in the GetNotification Function (down below) that may cause this problem ? or it is from the Android's system?

[I even noticed that sometimes if i turn off the wifi and back on again i get the missing notifications that should have been sent to the device ( i am 100% sure that i was connected to the internet when receiving any notifications)]

Sending a notification code:

```
public void SendNotification(final Context context, String requestToken, final String serverKey, String fcmUrl, final Requests request)
{
    String msg = "msg";
    String title = "title";
    JSONObject obj = null;
    JSONObject objData = null;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject();
        objData = new JSONObject();
        objData.put("body", msg);
        objData.put("title", title);
        obj.put("to", requestToken);
        obj.put("notification", objData);

    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest =
            new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,fcmUrl, obj,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                        {
                            Util.makeToast(context,"Success");
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                        {
                            Util.makeToast(context,"Fail");
                        }
                    })
            {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
                {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("Authorization", "key=" + serverKey);
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    return params;
                }
            };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    int socketTimeout = 1000 * 60;// 60 seconds
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

And this will create a notification in my service class that is implementing the FirebaseMessagingService :

```
private void GetNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainController.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("serve","PLEASE");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: `GetNotification` method looks fine. check on debug in first called method (breakpoint) that you are receiving any info at all. note that Google service may ban you temporary, when you make to much and to often requests to theirs server-side

Comment: @snachmsm yes i checked that before, i receive info.

Comment: @snachmsm "*note that Google service may ban you temporary, when you make to much and to often requests to theirs server-side*" - Could you point me out to a source for this behavior? I'm curious about GPS restrictions.

Comment: don't have source, I'm basing on my own experiences during my first implementing GCM (some time ago) for commercial use. Posted code is fine, so problem must be lying somewhere in the middle (you said that you are shure you receive push broadcast everytime and `GetNotification` should show notification also eveytime)